# Domain Forwarding Page Rule Not Working (CloudFlare)

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have a java webapplication hosted on AWS Beanstalk. And For DNS Settings of my domain I am using cloudflare.

I want my domiain (mydomain.com to forward to www.mydomain.com). I have set up a page rule for the same. Which looks like this
mydomain.com/* 301 Permanent Redirect to www.mydomain.com/$1 . Still when I open http:// mydomain.com it shows 'This Site can't be reached'

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works.

Note: For this setting to work, Traffic of your non-www domain must pass through cloudflare. You can check this in your DNS settings. You should have a CNAME record for example.com with active cloud. Shown as below.

http://www.5balloons.info/page-rules-in-cloudflare-to-forward-pages-from-non-www-to-www-domain/